# Angular acceleration of a car door

Tags: homework-and-exercises, torque, rigid-body-dynamics

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WpIf.jpg

Edit: i uploaded to the site but it came out really blurry so heres the imgur link

I don't get the solution at all, where does the -ma r cos theta come from? (Sorry on my phone)

Their kinematic equation doesn't seem to have much relevance to the rest of the problem besides the photo resolving the acceleration into the normal and tangential components.

What I get is this:
[image: my attempt]

Comment: Here's imgur link to my attempt http://imgur.com/x1UCx3N

Answer (score 1):

Consider the hinge reaction forces $(F_x,F_y)$ and take the balance of moments about the center of mass. The forces are found from the acceleration of the center of mass and the balance of forces yields the rotational acceleration of the door.

I call point *C* the center of mass and *A* the hinge. They are separated by distance $c$. I flipped the problem about the y-axis in order to make a positive angle counter clockwise.

1. Kinematics of the center of mass 
   $$\begin{align} 
     {x}_C & = {x}_A - c \sin \theta \\ 
     {y}_C & = {y}_A + c \cos\theta 
   \end{align}$$
   $$\begin{align} 
     \dot{x}_C & = \dot{x}_A - c \dot{\theta} \cos\theta \\ 
     \dot{y}_C & = \dot{y}_A - c \dot{\theta} \sin\theta 
   \end{align}$$
   $$\begin{align} 
     \ddot{x}_C & = \ddot{x}_A - c \ddot{\theta} \cos\theta + c \dot{\theta}^2 \sin\theta \\ 
     \ddot{y}_C & = \ddot{y}_A - c \ddot{\theta} \sin\theta - c \dot{\theta}^2 \cos\theta
   \end{align}$$
2. Hinge Forces with the car acceleration $\ddot{x}_A = a$ and $\ddot{y}_A = 0$
   $$\begin{align} 
     F_x & = m \left( a - c \ddot{\theta} \cos\theta + c \dot{\theta}^2 \sin\theta \right)\\ 
     F_y & = m \left(  - c \ddot{\theta} \sin\theta - c \dot{\theta}^2 \cos\theta \right)
   \end{align}$$
3. Balance of moments on the center of mass
   $$ M_C = F_x c \cos\theta + F_y c \sin\theta = m c \left( a \cos\theta - c \ddot{\theta} \right)$$
4. Rotational acceleration
   $$ \left. M_C  = I_C \ddot{\theta} \right\}  \boxed{ \ddot{\theta} =m\,a \frac{ c \cos\theta}{I_C + m c^2} } $$
5. Integration of acceleration
   $$ \int \dot{\theta} {\rm d}\dot{\theta} =  \int \ddot{\theta} {\rm d} \theta \\
   \frac{1}{2} \dot{\theta}^2 = m \, a \frac{c \sin\theta}{I_C + m  c^2} $$